# Crash when running on iPad Pro Simulator [Unity 5.2.2p1]

Tags: ipad, unity-game-engine, crash, ios-simulator, ios9

When trying to run my game on iPad Pro Simulator I'm getting the following crash:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _UnityParseCommandLine
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Users/eduardocoelho/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4944B945-6DFA-4DF4-830C-6084EBB9F754/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/326A72B2-584D-4CFB-9E1C-2FFA283A9BA0/klondikesolitaire.app/klondikesolitaire
>
> Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _UnityParseCommandLine
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Users/eduardocoelho/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4944B945-6DFA-4DF4-830C-6084EBB9F754/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/326A72B2-584D-4CFB-9E1C-2FFA283A9BA0/klondikesolitaire.app/klondikesolitaire
>
> Expected in: flat namespace

The app runs normally on another simulators.

My config is as follows:

- Unity 5.2.2p1
- XCode 7.1 (7B91b)
- Base SDK: iOS 9.1

How can I run my game on iPad Pro Simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never have any reason to use `-flat_namespace` and `-undefined lookup` when linking.  99.9999% of the time, they used to mask other bugs.  If you remove those from your linker flags (eg: OTHER_LDFLAGS), you'll get a proper error at link time instead of at runtime.

The error will indicate that you either forgot to link the library that provides the implementation of UnityParseCommandLine, or that library does not have a valid slice for the platform and architecture you are building for.

Comment: Actually, I didn't change any linker flags in the Xcode project. I'm just attempting to run the project generated by Unity. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug with whatever Unity does to generate the project.